# How to navigate to connected iPhone? Filesystem path to `afc://`?

Tags: filesystem, iphone

When I connect my iPhone to Ubuntu 11.10, it gets automounted as `afc://ca60751cc4b1ebb427c2f9da324914b0643a21f8/` and I can see that there are photos stored in `afc://ca60751cc4b1ebb427c2f9da324914b0643a21f8/DCIM/103APPLE`.

I would like to use programs to access these photo files, but they don't accept the `afc://` protocol -- they accept only normal file system paths.

**Is there a "normal file system equivalent" to `afc://` paths?**

Comment: Is there anything in your `/media` directory?  That's most often where external drives/gadgets are mounted.  Run a quick `ls /media` and post the output please

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? And what iOS version on iPhone?

Comment: 11.10 (I've updated the question.)

Comment: Back when i was using 11.10 en a iphone, i plugged in my iphone and get a message-window saying "there has bin pictures found on a removable media whit what program do you like to open"!? if you don't get that window. Just open shotwell and look for a iphone icon on the right side. if you click it shotwell will read all the available images on your iphone, and with shotwell you can also import all the images. :)

Answer (score 8):

If you're using gfvs to mount (**sudo idevicepair pair**), after pairing look here **/run/user/1000/gvfs/** And just **cd** (change directory) into the folder you're seeing (afc://1eefblablablablablablablablab).

Comment: `$ cd /run/user/1000/gvfs/afc*` will take you there at one go

Comment: The above will take you to the iDevice at port 3, but what if you wanted to go to port 1 just as you would if you typed afc://<serialNumber>:1/ into Nautilus?

Answer (score 3):

Right now, I'm finding my iPod files in ~/.gvfs/Phoenix's \iPod.  But this has been hit and miss for me---sometimes that is a directory, and sometimes it looks like a broken link!  But just now I unmounted the device, ran ls .gvfs, and found nothing; unplugged and replugged the device, ran ls again, and the files are there.

I have an iPod touch running iOS 5.0.1 connected to a laptop running Ubuntu 11.10.

EDIT: After some more research, I recommend the article at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS

which states that:

"GVFS is the virtual filesystem for the GNOME desktop, which allows users easy access to remote data via SFTP, FTP, WebDAV, SMB, and local data via HAL integration, OBEX and others.[1]

Attached resources are exposed via a URI syntax, for example smb://server01/gamedata or ftp://username:password@ftp.example.net/public_html, but are also mounted in the traditional manner under ~/.gvfs/ to make them available to older applications using standard POSIX commands and I/O."

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you determine that your device automounted at the location you specified (afc://...etc), and what did you use to get your device to automount?  Just curious :)

Comment: You are asking this yourself?

Comment: I think @PhoenixStormcrow was asking the OP, though it wasn't very clear.  Should have commented on the main question, or edited the answer.

Comment: I was indeed asking the OP, but didn't have the necessary privileges to comment on the main question. Then internet problems interfered with further use of the site. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

@PhoenixStormcrow, the information you are looking for can be found by right clicking and selecting Properties on any of the files/directories on the nautilus window showing your iPhone files. The long hex number you see there is actually your iPhone's UDID (unique device ID) and I would not post it publicly.