# Can't do anything with my iPad (3rd gen) using 13.04

Tags: 13.04, music, iphone, ipad, ios

I'm just trying to put new music on my iPad. I've tried to get iTunes to run using play on Linux as well as Wine. I've also tried to add music with both Banshee and Rhythmbox. I can't make anything work, but through libimobiledevice I am able to dock it and see the files, but nothing more. I'm sorry if this question has already been asked, but I can't find anything recent on the subject. Also I have an iPhone 4 and I'm experiencing the same issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://askubuntu.com/q/151584/12218) question and it's answer talk about transferring video files between an iPad and Ubuntu via USB.

The process should be the same with audio, document and image files you will have to use a general file browser app from iTunes such as iFiles or FileBrowser. Both can handle various file formats.

Additionally iFiles has an in-built file server which can be accessed over the network.
FileBrowser can access network shares.

There are many file manager applications in iTunes which can provide similar services.

*Note that I have no relation with either of the software mentioned above, it just happens to own both*