# mount afc://.../DCIM as a folder

Tags: 18.04, mount, iphone, photo-management

I'm using [Rapid Foto Downloader](https://damonlynch.net/rapid/documentation/#downloadingfromphones) 0.9.24 with my iPhone on 18.04LTS. Recently, it shows no photos (it does see the iPhone, when the latter is unmounted in Files). I'm able to [navigate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928750/how-do-i-access-ios-camera-pictures-on-ubuntu) to DCIM folder using `afc://blablablha` address in Files.

I wonder if I could make `afc://blablablha/DCIM` to look as a usual folder (mount?). Then I'd let Rapid Foto Downloader import files from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think I [found](https://askubuntu.com/a/579440/) it:
`/run/user/1000/gvfs/afc:host=blablablha/DCIM/`